# winform C# PreDefined Form for loading data

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, load

is there any predefined form for c# winform to load some data?

for example you select Load button. new form will show up and you browse for your file and select your file and then press load.
also you can select what type of files to show.

there is the same form for saving files.

should i make new form like this my self?

Comment: What type of file are you loading?

Comment: No. But you can write one and then use it a a Template you inherit from.

Comment: i dont think its important. its .txt @DavidBeaumont

Comment: thank you.do you know where i can get sample? @TaW

Comment: No, but it will be better to go for it yourself. Often the ready-made samples are much more complicated than what you really need..

Comment: You can use an OpenFileDialog Control to browse for the file and select the file and limit extension types, you can use the RichTextBox Control to display the Text.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).